# Regex Installed with Pip but Not Recognized

Tags: python, regex, pip

So I am trying to parse data from a file using regular expressions.

I've successfully installed regex...

```
pip install regex
Requirement already satisfied: regex in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2020.7.14)
```

And I'm including the module in my Python file....

```
import regex
```

But when I run my script I get the following error:

```
parser.py 14 <module>
import regex

ModuleNotFoundError:
No module named 'regex'
```

I have absolutely no clue as to what I'm doing wrong. Why is it not recognizing that I have the regex module installed? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you save you script as `regex.py` in the Python folder? Rename it.

Comment: Hi Wiktor. Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Why would I need to rename the file if pip is taking care of the install for me?

Comment: Furthermore, when I go to the directory specified after I type `pip install regex` I find regex.py there. Is there some sort of PATH variable for python I need to alter for it to find the regex.py file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!

Turns out pip and python were in totally different directories:

```
$ where pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
$ where python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
```

All I had to do to fix that was this:

```
python -m pip install regex
```

This ensured that regex was installed to the /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `import re` and use it instead (it's built-in).

Comment: Hi Herr Flick. Re doesn't have the same level of functionality as Regex, which is why I am insistent on using it.

Comment: Fair enough. have you tried checking if the necessary paths are in your PATH environment variable (assuming you are using windows)?

Comment: I am using MacOS. When I run `echo $PATH` the directory that regex.py is located in is also there: [. . . :/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages: . . .]